# Splitting overlap between polygons into disjoint sets using shapely?

Tags: topology, shapely

I have two overlapping `shapely` polygons A and B. I want to divide their intersection into two pieces, such that one part of the intersection is the set of points in `A.intersection(B)` (or symmetrically, `B.intersection(A)` to the boundary of `A-B`, and the other is the set of points closer to the boundary of `B-A`.

Is there an way to do this in `shapely` other than applying a brute-force mesh and checking the distance to each polygon's boundary?

Comment: when you say set of points, do you mean to find the points of A that are inside of B??

Comment: seems like .intersection() or .difference() method would be the place to start anyway

Comment: Thanks, @rickD, I clarified the question a little; yes, I'm talking about the points in the intersection of A and B, or the points of A inside B.

Comment: You can convert the Intersection to Points, Polygons A,B to lines. The normal Shapely Intersection should work to separate the Intersection Points by source polygon, eg, Intersection_pts.intersect(line_A)

Comment: Right, but they won't be disjoint, I believe; I'm trying to partition the intersection between the two intersecting polygons exactly.

Comment: oh, are you trying to find a center line of the overlapping polygon, that would begin and end at the 2 points where their exteriors touch? Like a line of midpoints between the 2 lines?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I'm not sure how to orient the boundaries to line the two up, or if that even makes sense in the case that the polygons overlap in more than one place, or overlap in a circle/spiral. I don't want to make any assumptions on the nature of the intersection.