# Creating sub-watershed within a basin

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, saga, watershed

I am a beginner to QGIS. My problem is I tried to create sub-catchment within a basin by using provided point datasets (river gauge location). In total, I have 12 measuring points (i.e 12 pairs of x and y coordinates) within my basin. I want to delineate all catchments within basin on the basis of provided coordinates ( not on the basis of minimum or maximum cell that r.watershed has.) I am looking for the function in 'hydrology' extension tool of ArcMap.

Comment: Look through my answer to the question listed on this link, maybe some steps will help to find the right solution, go for it --https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264416/splitting-overlap-between-polygons-and-assign-to-nearest-polygon-using-postgis/283047#283047

Comment: Welcome to the forum. It is expected that you have done your own research and trying something before asking for help. Have a look to these tutorials (https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Hydrological_Sciences and https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Creating_watersheds). When you face a more specific problem, edit your question to see what is stoping you and then it is easier to help you